# problems getting HTTPRiot working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

I've got an iphone app where I'm trying to use HTTPRiot to make some API calls to a web app.  Problem is I can't see that none of the HTTPRiot delegate methods are being called.  I've got a log in all the delegate methods, and I'm also looking at the webserver log.  I see that the URL is being hit.

```
//API.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <HTTPRiot/HTTPRiot.h>


@interface API : HRRestModel {

}

+(void)runTest;

@end



//API.m
#import "API.h"


@implementation API


+ (void)initialize {

    NSLog(@"api initialize");

    [self setDelegate:self];
    [self setBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:3000/api"]];
    [self setBasicAuthWithUsername:@"demo" password:@"123456"];

    NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"1234567" forKey:@"api_key"];
    [self setDefaultParams:params];


}//end initialize


+(void)runTest {

    NSLog(@"api run test");

    // Would send a request to http://localhost:1234/api/people/1?api_key=1234567
    [self getPath:@"/save_diet" withOptions:nil object:nil];
}


+(void)restConnection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReturnResource:(id)resource object:(id)object {
    NSLog(@"didReturnResource");
}



+(void)restConnection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response object:(id)object {
    NSLog(@"didReceiveResponse");
}



+(void)restConnection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveParseError:(NSError *)error responseBody:(NSString *)body object:(id)object {
    NSLog(@"didReceiveParseError");
}



+(void)restConnection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveError:(NSError *)error response:(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response object:(id)object {
    NSLog(@"didReceiveError");
}



+(void)restConnection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error object:(id)object {
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError");
}


@end


//test code
[API runTest];


//log output
```

Answer (score 0):

2 Things:

1-- 
you're using class methods wrong. 
+initialize is a method that is guaranteed to be called once by the runtime. It's good for setting up static variables and the like (in a thread safe way)

you want to use -(id)init for setting that up. You are calling 'self' in a class method for both initialize and runTest, which either is garbage or nil. Make runTest an instance method instead, and I am sure you'll get results.

2 --
Check the stuff coming in and out of the app using Charles.

http://www.charlesproxy.com/

If you're getting the expected responses from the server, then yeah, its your app.

Comment: The code (+initialize and the others) are taken pretty much straight from the HTTPRiot docs, I changed the code to use class methods instead of instance methods for the delegate methods, and I got didReceiveResponse: to get called, however didReturnResource: doesnt.